# Changing a color of a <shape> defined in XML programatically

Tags: android, xml

I am unsure of a best way to change the color of a  that I defined in xml programatically. Suppose I have the following shape element:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#00FF7F"/>
</shape>
```

and the following View...

```xml
<View android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/rect4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rect2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rect1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```

How would I be able to change the color of the rectangle/view in my program? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it like this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.rect4);
v.setBackground(R.drawable.rectangle);
```

Store you xml file with name **rectangle.xml** in **drawable** folder ,  that's it

Comment: @Saeed i know but i think , questioner want it to adjust with xml , so that's what i answered , did i do wrong ?

Comment: @Saeed Would you mind to point out what way of change would you recommend then?

Comment: Getting `GradientDrawable` of view and then change the color

Answer (score 0):

Try as bellow .

```
GradientDrawable backgroundShape = (GradientDrawable)btn.getBackground();
backgroundShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Do you need to set many different colors or do you want to switch between two colors?

You could for example define another shape (or multiple other shapes) that differ only in color and set the different shapes to the view.

However, if you only need a rectangle, you could just set directly a color as background to the view.

Or you could define a state selector with different colors for different states. And even define your own custom states.

Though, I have no idea what would be best suited to your needs.